# Building FDO source code on Windows

Tags: arcgis, osgeo, fdo

I'm trying to compile the FDO source code (http://fdo.osgeo.org/) on Windows to be able to use the FDO provider for ArcSDE.

The FDO build instructions say I need ArcSDE client SDK installed. I am not sure which installer would this be part of. I do have an installer for ArcSDE server components but it needs that I have Oracle installed on my machine. Is there an easier way to just get the ArcSDE Client SDK. I have gone through the information on the ESRI website, but couldn't find an easy answer.

I was wondering if anyone here has faced similar issues building the FDO code and can share their experience. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.